# Generally Ada seems to compile code slower than similar C code, why is this?

Tags: c, ada

When I compile programs in Ada, I typically notice a longer compile time for code of similar length and of similar content to programs written in C or C++.

While it is true that it comes down to the compiler and system to determine compile time the Ada compilation generally takes longer.  Is this process radically different than the compile/link process of C or C++. Does it consist of different stages?

What about the Ada compilation process makes the compilation take longer than ?

Comment: Why's the fat guy run slower than the athlete?

Comment: I use around 4 or 5 C compilers, and they all take a different length of time to compile the same source

Comment: I use 1 C compiler, and it takes a different amount of time to compile the same source depending on which optimisations I ask it to do.

Comment: This has been an issue since the early days of Ada. It is largely a function of the language complexity. For example the VAX C and VAX Ada compilers used the same backend but Ada compilation was much slower.

Answer (score 4):

It is all about the amount of time and effort put into making the compiler fast.

Compilers that have a broader scope tend to have more money to invest in making fast; however, sometimes there are other elements at stake.  For example, the details of a compiler might include static type checking, various "extra" correctness checks, and other items (programming contract compliance, code quality, etc) that might adjust the compile time.

Ada tends to have had less money thrown at its compiler, and it is likely a slightly more complex language to parse than C.  Both of these factors lend themselves to making it likely that its compiler will be slower.

Note that speed of compilation has little to do with the "quality" of the language.  While C might have a larger footprint, Ada has made its mark on the programming world in other ways.